# How does Android know there is not enough space to install app

Tags: android, mobile, storage

There is plenty solutions to the questions "How to fix insufficient storage space" (as far as I know, all of them boil down to removing data on the disk).  But, with an algorithm design mindset, I would like to know how to calculate whether there is enough space to install an app, before the user stumbles upon the error.

We know that is related to the way the devices partition the available storage. But, how that works, exactly? Is the algorithm device dependent?  Or maybe the devices can just configure the size for their partitions?

Bonus points to the answers comparing the way Android does to the other platforms.

(Please! Focus on the question, as I will downvote answers to "How to fix insufficient storage space" unaccompanied of answers to the actual question! This warning will be removed after some time to keep this question clean.)

Comment: You are asking several questions at once Ribamar. I would like to help you, but I can't seem to understand what you're really asking for ?

Comment: I am supposing you understood since you answered  well the question.

Answer (score 0):

As far as "How to fix insufficient storage space", well android know's when a storage disk space is below 10% for a 4GB drive, the system will notify the user. This value goes down by 25% as the size of the disk goes up 4GB. Thus if the disk size is 8GB, the user will be notified when it's below 7.5%. When it is 16% in size, the user will be notified when the space is below 5% and so one

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is this specified anywhere?